# Jquery add class not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-4

I am using a php model function to pass some information into javascript, so that I can add a class to an element.

It looks like this in the javascript (this is Laravel 4's blade syntax):

```
@if(Auth::user())
  <?php $artist_likes = Fanartist::profile_fan_likes(Auth::user()->id); ?>
  @foreach($artist_likes as $like)
  $("#{{$like->id}}").addClass('individual-heart-hover');
  @endforeach
@endif
```

This is the element:

```
<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x individual-heart" id="{{$artist->id}}"></i>
</span>
```

When I look at the page source, I see that the id in the element and the #like->id element are both rendering as the same number (as they should), but the class is not being added to the element?  Am I missing something?  Thank you.

Comment: Is `$artist->id` just a number? That would be invalid HTML and probably the reason that it doesn't work. Another reason might be that the Javascript isn't running after DOM load.

Comment: it's just a number...it's just a php echo using blade syntax

Comment: What is your DOCTYPE? If you aren't using HTML5, 'just a number' in the ID-attribute isn't valid.

Comment: It should work anyway. Not all invalid HTML causes actual problems. Duplicate IDs would be a problem, but numeric IDs? AFAIK they don't cause problems.

Comment: @user1072337 A very good practise would be to answer your own question, marking it as the valid answer, marking this question as answered and thereby giving a neat way to answer this question for future questioners :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to use number-only IDs in HTML:

`ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`